# Searching a column value that has couple records with some different specified values

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a database:

```
|id|surname|name
| 1|Smith  |John
| 2|Smith  |Mike
| 3|Smith  |Bob
| 4|Knope  |John
| 5|Knope  |Mike
| 6|Knope  |Dick
| 7|Pratt  |John
| 8|Pratt  |Jill
| 9|Pratt  |James
```

and I want to find a family name that has in it John, Mike and Bob. I want it to return Smith. Or I want to search for a family that has in it John and Mike and I want it to return Smith and Knope. How can I do that?

the results that I want to get are above but here's the same with nicer form:
I'm looking for family that has Jon, Mike, Bob. I want to get:

```
|surname|
|Smith  |
```

Then I want to look for John and Mike only and I want to get:

```
|surname|
|Smith  |
|Knope  |
```

Comment: Do you want both results?

Comment: Specify the expected result. And show us your current query attempt.

Comment: Is it SQL-Server? Then please tag it.

Comment: Hint: GROUP BY, HAVING, COUNT().

Comment: Which [DBMS product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Answer (score 0):

Based on your explantions you can do something like this:

```
declare @table table (it int, surename varchar(50),name1 varchar(50))

insert into @table

values
(1,'Smith','John'),
(2,'Smith','Mike'),
(3,'Smith','Bob' ),
(4,'Knope','John'),
(5,'Knope','Mike'),
(6,'Knope','Dick'),
(7,'Pratt','John'),
(8,'Pratt','Jill'),
(9,'Pratt','James')

select * from @table
where name1 in ('john','mike','bob') and surename = 'smith'

union 

select * from @table
where name1 in('john','mike') and surename in ('smith','knope')
```

**Result**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your input has dynamically multiple values. Thus, I will assume you have put all of the names you want the family to include in a table #i with field "name". Then, you want all families for which no name specified in your input is missing.

```
select *
from (select distinct surename from yourtable)surnames
where not exists
(
    select 1 from #i
    where not exists
    (
        select 1 
        from yourtable t
        where 
            t.surename=surnames.surename
            and #i.name=t.name
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This works in SQL Server - written before your question was tagged with PostgreSQL.

Set up the test data:

```
DECLARE @Names TABLE (ID INTEGER IDENTITY, Surname VARCHAR(50), Forenames VARCHAR(50));

INSERT
    @Names (Surname, Forenames)
VALUES
    ('Smith', 'John'),
    ('Smith', 'Mike'),
    ('Smith', 'Bob' ),
    ('Knope', 'John'),
    ('Knope', 'Mike'),
    ('Knope', 'Dick'),
    ('Pratt', 'John'),
    ('Pratt', 'Jill'),
    ('Pratt', 'James');
```

Declare a table variable containing the forenames you'd like to match. This acts as a parameter, so you should edit the values we insert to test the results:

```
DECLARE @ForenamesToSearch TABLE (Forenames VARCHAR(50));

INSERT
    @ForenamesToSearch
VALUES
    ('John')
    , ('Mike')
    , ('Bob');
```

Finally we use GROUP BY and HAVING COUNT to ensure the number of names matches exactly.

```
SELECT
    Surname
FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT Forenames, Surname FROM @Names) Names
    INNER JOIN @ForenamesToSearch Forenames ON Names.Forenames = Forenames.Forenames
GROUP BY
    Surname
HAVING
    COUNT(1) = (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM @ForenamesToSearch);
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the best way to do this but you can try the following for Postgresql:

```
select * 
from
(
select 
    concat(',' , string_agg(name1,',') , ',') as X,
    surname
from 
    table_name as A
group BY 
    surname
) As B
Where B.X like '%,John,%' And B.X like '%,Mike,%' And B.X like '%,Bob,%';
```

[SQLFIDDLE DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/ef8e4/12/0)

The following is for SQL server:

```
select * from
(
select 
    ', ' + STUFF((SELECT ', ' + name1 FROM table_name WHERE surname = A.surname FOR XML PATH('')),1,2,'') + ',' as X,
    surname
from 
    table_name as A
group BY 
    surname
) as B
Where B.X like '%, John,%' And B.X like '%, Mike,%' And B.X like '%, Bob,%';
```

[SQLFIDDLE DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/c3429/20/0)